# `Thread.currentThread()` not constant during construction and runtime?

Tags: java, multithreading

After spending too much time with my debugger, I stumbled upon something interesting that was not clear to me yet.  I would like someone with more Java experience to explain and confirm this:

Instead of using `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` every time, I shortened things to `thisThread.isInterrupted()`.  I declared `thisThread` as `private Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread()` in my Runnable implementation.  Little did I know that during runtime, `thisThread` and `Thread.currentThread()` refer to two different things.  The first one "reads" `Thread[main,5,main]`, the second one "reads" `Thread[Thread-1,5,main]`.

It seems as if `Thread.currentThread()` refers to the thread that constructs the Runnable implementation (main) during construction and it refers to the independent, fully-constructed thread once the thread is started.

Is that a correct interpretation of what is going on internally?

I am seeking to understand why `Thread.currentThread()` in the class' header is not the same as `Thread.currentThread()` in `run()`.

```
public class Temp implements Runnable {
    
    private Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
    
    public void run() {
        
        while ( !thisThread.isInterrupted() ) {
            
            //[...]
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Which thread executes `Thread.currentThread()`?  Which thread executes `run()`?  `currentThread()` returns a reference to the current Thread object, not a magic reference that's dynamically resolved to whatever the current thread happens to be later on.

Comment: *"Is that a correct interpretation of what is going on internally?"* - Basically yes ... in the scenario that you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `thisThread` is set during construction of the Runnable (to the thread that called the constructor).

The current thread during `run` will be whatever thread is executing that method.

Usually, those are two different Threads.

For example:

```
executorService.submit(new Temp());
```

Here, the thread that called the constructor will become `thisThread`, but the `run` method will be called by the ExecutorService, which could be using a pool of background threads.

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate `Temp`, you invoke the constructor from the main thread. So, the value will be the main thread. Since you keep it in `thisThread`, it will always show the main thread. But if you change `thisThread` to a function, whenever you call it, it will return you the thread where actually you are in.